# Configure mod_proxy to ignore a domain/url

Tags: centos, apache-2.4, proxy, httpd, mod-proxy

I have mod_proxy configured as public proxy, so users can use my server (/ip) while browsing the web ...

How can I set mod_proxy to ignore a certain url/domain like "google" and directly show that request to user (just like it would not use a proxy) ?

**Edit:** I mean I set apache to work as proxy, so users can set my IP as proxy in their internet settings. Now when they browse the web they can hide their real ip from websites. 
But for some domains like Google.com I want them to connect directly.
Current httpd.conf is like this:

```
ProxyRequests On
ProxyVia On

<Proxy "*">
</Proxy>
```

Comment: Please clarify what exactly you mean by "users can use my server (/ip) while browsing the web".

Comment: @TeroKilkanen I added details.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how did you configure the main rule, but generally like this:

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*)  http://$1 [P,L]
```

You can also add some `RewriteCond` clauses for more fine-grained control.

Comment: I added some details to question. Maybe I don't understand how proxies work, but can I edit .htaccess and add rewrite rules and test with %{HTTP_HOST} ? But if I just redirect a user to another domain their browser will simply open that url using connection settings (still my proxy).

Comment: You cannot control whether the user browser will use your proxy or not using only your proxy. You can partially achieve this effect by using *web proxy auto discovery* (WPAD), but basically you are reingventing the wheel.

Comment: Thanks. This is not generally possible ? For example once user set my IP as his "proxy", I cannot generally disable all proxy functionality and send user directly to requested URL showing user's real IP ?

Comment: Indeed, you can't.